# How to use the Gmail API to read the subjects of emails sent from a yahoo group

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, gmail-api, google-oauth, yahoo-api

I'm using the Gmail API with Oauth 2 to read all of my emails and print out the subject and the date, like so:

```
for m in email_list:      
        msg = service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=m["id"], format="full").execute()
        header_list = msg["payload"]["headers"]

        for i in header_list:
            nameindict=i["name"]
                if nameindict=="Subject":
                    print(i["value"])
                if nameindict=="Date":
                    print(i["value"])
```

this section is pasted into the main() function of the gmail API example, found here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

However, there's two problems:

-Sometimes, it misses the subject. I checked the full output and found that some outputs didn't have a subject attached, but couldn't find out why.

-This doesn't seem to work with email sent from a Yahoo group. The "full" option returns a jumble of letters and numbers, but no subject or readable date and time sent. Does anyone know if this is possible, and how I can do it?

Comment: Could you post an example of what you get from Yahoo groups? Maybe looking at that jumble will help.

Comment: I think there might be some restrictions to Yahoo mail which was mentioned in [How to Read Your Inbox Retrieving Email](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/2/post/2-Retrieving-email-messages-using-PHP-from-Gmail-Hotmail-and-Yahoo-via-POP3.html).